# SQLAlchemy column from orm composite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use `composite` (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html#mapper-composite) to create a `Column` object on the table?  I have tried using `column_property` and a couple other things, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Do you mean a composite type column such as in [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)? The answer to your first sentence is "no", the linked [composite](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html#sqlalchemy.orm.composite) is for adding an ORM-handled composite attribute that represents a group of columns.

Comment: Yes, you understood my question correctly.  I was hoping there was a way to make a Column from the orm attribute.  I'm trying to work out a way to do something that can use a postgres composite column, but doesn't have to.  I have used UserDefinedType to make a composite type before, so I might end up doing that.

Comment: [sqlalchemy_utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)' [CompositeType](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.pg_composite) might be of help to you – or not. It creates a `Column` with a composite type that groups other `Column`s (different from the ORM-version).